# couldn't enable SOAP in cent os 6.4 (Final)

Tags: php, apache, soap, centos

I have installed **CentOS release 6.4 (Final)** in server.

**I had installed SOAP library successfully but coun't enable it on server.**

I had done following steps on server.

Run this command in root folder

```
find -name soap.so
```

it will return following

```
./usr/lib64/php/modules/soap
```

so i set this line `extension='./usr/lib64/php/modules/soap.so'` in `/etc/php.ini` file and restart httpd services in cent os 6. but still it couldn't enable soap service i checked in php_info(), any idea?

Answer (score 0):

These steps solved my problem 
http://www.linglom.com/administration/enable-php-extensions-with-easyapache-on-whm-cpanel